# How to match until hitting a certain character?

Tags: regex

I apologize if my question is stupid. I just stared learning regex a few hours back.

I am trying to extract all hashtags

- until it reaches a space or newline
- cannot have more than two # in a row

Special characters are allowed until it reaches a space/a hastag/newline

Here is my current regex: `\#{1}(\S|\N)`

I tried changing it to `\#{1}.+(\S|\N)` because i assumed the `.+` will allow it to keep matching until it reaches a new line or space

```
======================TESTHASH========================
#3!x_j@`(/l3W#qfSnl#6R7x1b,jBb0p#Oq/:o#!tH3AITK^Yyp#B,
#qwe#%#T &#v#v#N###O###2#` `S}^&9 #M # Aa23%2##p#?#w#a
#123#9#Z a%h#&#C###;###? a#u#g#Q#r#8# #a#A#l#p#r#b#}#c
#R#M#(#p###K###l###1###b 2#D\'>.w/Y_2 sha2&2{] #4x$D~kR
#lbTb1k3# #Dlo ## #j# #W H#tjsR.Lzkc  #B*xt&nFty?il#jp
#>p8BTU2###PW!aB###z###-VM (s82hdk#T 8sUJWfuy2#-#f~fh)
#d{jyi|^ofYD#q)!#special~!@$%^&*()#_+`-=[];\',./?><\":}{
======================TESTHASH========================
```

Comment: Your question isn't stupid, but it is unclear.  Can you highlight the actual hash tags in your sample data?  Or, better yet, give us many examples of what hash tags look like here.

Comment: When you say "cannot have more than two # in a row", should it match "##" as two empty hashtags or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How about `#[^#\s\n]+`?**

- It matches all hashtags.
- It stops at spaces and newlines.
- It doesn't match two hashtags in a row. (This sentence is a bit ambiguous; is `##` two hashtags of length zero, or zero hashtags? `#[^#\s\n]*` is equivalent to Sweeper's regex, but without the look-ahead. `#[^#\s\n]+` additionally requires that hashtags don't have zero characters after them.)
- All characters allowed after hashtag except hashtag, space and newline.

**This is what `#[^#\s\n]+` matches:**

[image: regex101 match image]

It seems to secretly spell out "NICE"; I wonder if this is an exercise and you're using StackOverflow to think for you? :-)

Answer (score 3):

I made a few changes to your regex to get it match these:

[image]

This is the regex:

```
\#.*?(?=\s|\n|\#|$)
```

Changes I've made:

- used a lazy "zero or more" quantifier `*?`. This means that it will keep matching until `(?=\s|\n|\#|$)` is not true, whereas with a greedy quantifier, it will match all the way to the end of the line, then backtracks until `(?=\s|\n|\#|$)` is true.
- removed `{1}`, this is unnecessary
- added more options to the end. I've added `\#` and `$`. They are characters that when encountered, should stop the match.
- used a lookahead. This avoids getting another `#` into the match.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dxnSGx/1)

Comment: Why not just `#[^#\s\n]*` and why escape `#`?

Comment: @SimonShine I started off with OP's regex and my head wasn't thinking in that direction. I escaped # just in case it has some special meaning in OP's regex flavour. I saw OP escape it, so I thought maybe that's for a reason.

Comment: Thank you that solved it. But may I know how it can be changed such that it only matches those with minimum length 1 after the hash? At the moment, single hashes are being matched.

Comment: @Zolly oh, I thought you want to match single hashes. Then the accepted solution would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
\#[^\s\#]*(\s|\#)
```

Matches a # followed by any number of chars other than whitespace and # which is followed by a whitespace or #

This should work

Comment: You most likely don't need to escape `#` (in which regex dialect is this a special character?) and you're forgetting a hashtag at the end of input, e.g. "#foo" - this is neither followed by `\s` nor `#`. https://regex101.com/r/cTDatK/1

Comment: I think \s natches newline

Comment: Yes, it does, but it doesn't match end-of-line. So it does not match "#foo".

Comment: I meant \s matches \n or EOL. At least py doc says so

Comment: No, [the docs don't](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). `import re; re.match(r'\s', "") is None` in a Python REPL. `\s` matches one (not zero) whitespace chars. EOL isn't a char, but a zero-width condition. You can fix your regex by changing it to `#[^\s#]*(\s|#|$)`; but this last `(\s|#|$)` includes the first whitespace or `#` after the hashtag. If you remove the last part (you don't need it because of the negative character group), you're closer to the regex I suggested, and if you change it into a look-ahead (to avoid including it in the match), you're closer to Sweeper's regex.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I mixed up EOL and \n. My bad. Sorry. Actually I'm very new to regex. Moreover I don't use regex regularly. But thanks for the eye opener.